# the sorting goes wrong when sorting the descending numbers stored in an array and there is minor error in bubble sort

Tags: arrays, sorting, bubble-sort, insertion-sort, selection-sort

Problem:
1. Sorting the worst cases shows only the half of the result in all of the sorting methods.

Goal:
1. To sort the best case, average, and worst case using the bubble sort, insertion sort, and selection sort.

Tried fixes:
1. Change the values of the arrays.
2. Checked the sorting itself.
3. Make the case values to show that it is correct.

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Random {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] bestCase = ascRan();
    int[] average = ran();
    int[] worstCase = desRan();

    System.out.println("Best Case: \t\t"    + Arrays.toString(bestCase));
    System.out.println("Average: \t\t"      + Arrays.toString(average));
    System.out.println("Worst Case: \t"     + Arrays.toString(worstCase));

    System.out.println("\nCurrent Time(ms): " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println("Current Time(ns): " + System.nanoTime());
    System.out.println();

    //Best Cases
    System.out.println("Bubble (Best Case)");
    int[]bSortBest = bubbleSort(bestCase);
    print(bSortBest);
    System.out.println("Insert (Best Case)");
    int[]iSortBest = insertionSort(bestCase);
    print(iSortBest);
    System.out.println("Select (Best Case)");
    int[]sSortBest = selectionSort(bestCase);
    print(sSortBest);

    //Average
    System.out.println("Bubble (Average)");
    int[]bSortAverage = bubbleSort(average);
    print(bSortAverage);
    System.out.println("Insert (Average)");
    int[]iSortAverage = insertionSort(average);
    print(iSortAverage);
    System.out.println("Select (Average)");
    int[]sSortAverage = selectionSort(average);
    print(sSortAverage);

    //Worst Cases
    System.out.println("Bubble (Worst Case)");
    int[]bSortWorst = bubbleSort(worstCase);
    print(bSortWorst);
    System.out.println("Insert (Worst Case)");
    int[]iSortWorst = insertionSort(worstCase);
    print(iSortWorst);
    System.out.println("Select (Worst Case)");
    int[]sSortWorst = selectionSort(worstCase);
    print(sSortWorst);
}

//Random 0-99
public static int[] ran() {
    int[] a = new int[101];
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.length -1; i++) {
        a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }
    return a;
}

//0-99
public static int[] ascRan() {
    int[] b = new int[100];
    int min;
    int max = 99;

    for(min = 0; min <= max; min++){
        b[min] = min;
    }
    return b;
}

//99-0
public static int[] desRan() {
    int[] c = new int[100];
    int min;
    int max = 99;

    for(min = 0; min <= max; min++){
        c[min] = max;
        max--;
    }
    return c;
}

public static int[]bubbleSort(int[] arr){
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > (arr[j + 1])) {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

public static int[]insertionSort(int[] arr){
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        int key = arr[i];
        int j= i-1;
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key){
            arr[j+1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j+1]= key;
    }
    return arr;
}

public static int[]selectionSort(int[] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        int minimum = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[minimum]) {
                minimum = j;
            }
            int temp = arr[minimum];
            arr[minimum] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

public static void print(int arr[]) {
    int n = arr.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Time(ms): " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println("Current Time(ns): " + System.nanoTime());
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

1. Average Case for bubble sort
   0 1 1 2 2 4 5 5 6 7 8 10 14 15 16 18 21 21 22 22 23 27 28 30 31 33 34 35 36 36 37 40 40 41 42 42 44 45 46 46 47 49 55 57 57 57 58 58 59 59 60 60 61 62 62 64 65 65 67 67 68 69 69 71 71 72 74 74 76 77 77 77 78 79 79 80 80 81 83 84 84 85 85 86 86 87 87 88 90 91 93 94 96 96 96 97 98 98 99 99 97 
   Current Time(ms): 1565701640559
   Current Time(ns): 91934126771600
2. Worst Case for bubble sort
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 0 
   Current Time(ms): 1565701640580
   Current Time(ns): 91934147301100
3. Worst Case for insertion sort
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
   Current Time(ms): 1565701640587
   Current Time(ns): 91934154307600
4. Worst Case for selection sort
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
   Current Time(ms): 1565701640589
   Current Time(ns): 91934156292200

1 has an invalid value at the end of the sort
2,3,4 does not show numbers 1-49

Comment: Bubblesort: `for(int j = 1; j < (arr.length - 1);j++){` why the `-1`?

Comment: fixed the bubble sort... Will update the question

Comment: Thanks for the help for that... Created my own version due to that

Comment: Worst cases... I'm still knowing what's my problem on my end.

Answer (score 0):

package edu.slu.prog1;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Random {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] bestCase = ascRan();
    int[] average = ran();
    int[] worstCase = desRan();

    System.out.println("Best Case: \t\t"    + Arrays.toString(bestCase));
    System.out.println("Average: \t\t"      + Arrays.toString(average));
    System.out.println("Worst Case: \t"     + Arrays.toString(worstCase));

    System.out.println("\nCurrent Time(ms): " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println("Current Time(ns): " + System.nanoTime());
    System.out.println();

    //Best Cases
    System.out.println("Bubble (Best Case)");
    int[]bSortBest = bubbleSort(bestCase);
    print(bSortBest);
    System.out.println("Insert (Best Case)");
    int[]iSortBest = insertionSort(bestCase);
    print(iSortBest);
    System.out.println("Select (Best Case)");
    int[]sSortBest = selectionSort(bestCase);
    print(sSortBest);

    //Average
    System.out.println("Bubble (Average)");
    int[]bSortAverage = bubbleSort(average);
    print(bSortAverage);
    System.out.println("Insert (Average)");
    int[]iSortAverage = insertionSort(average);
    print(iSortAverage);
    System.out.println("Select (Average)");
    int[]sSortAverage = selectionSort(average);
    print(sSortAverage);

    //Worst Cases
    System.out.println("Bubble (Worst Case)");
    int[]bSortWorst = bubbleSort(worstCase);
    print(bSortWorst);
    System.out.println("Insert (Worst Case)");
    int[]iSortWorst = insertionSort(worstCase);
    print(iSortWorst);
    System.out.println("Select (Worst Case)");
    int[]sSortWorst = selectionSort(worstCase);
    print(sSortWorst);
}

//Random 0-99
public static int[] ran() {
    int[] a = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.length -1; i++) {
        a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }
    return a;
}

//0-99
public static int[] ascRan() {
    int[] b = new int[100];
    int min;
    int max = 99;

    for(min = 0; min <= max; min++){
        b[min] = min;
    }
    return b;
}

//99-0
public static int[] desRan() {
    int[] c = new int[100];
    int min;
    int max = 99;
    int des = max;

    for(min = 0; min <= max; min++){
        c[min] = des;
        des--;
    }
    return c;
}

public static int[]bubbleSort(int[] arr){
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > (arr[j + 1])) {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

public static int[]insertionSort(int[] arr){
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        int key = arr[i];
        int j= i-1;
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key){
            arr[j+1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j+1]= key;
    }
    return arr;
}

public static int[]selectionSort(int[] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        int minimum = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[minimum]) {
                minimum = j;
            }
            int temp = arr[minimum];
            arr[minimum] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

public static void print(int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0, arrLength = arr.length; i < arrLength; i++) {
        int anArr = arr[i];
        System.out.print(anArr + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Time(ms): " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println("Current Time(ns): " + System.nanoTime());
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Comment: the descending order in the array has the faulty area so I fixed it